# how to display if the number is half-prime when the count reaches 3

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

This is the question that is asked..

> Write a java program that asks the user to enter a list of numbers between 1 and 100. The user needs to enter a 0 in order to end the list of input data. The program displays if each number is half-prime or not.
>   N is half-prime where the count of all divisors is equal three. For example 25 is half-prime, the divisors of 25 are 1, 5 and 25.

Here is my progress....

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 100: (0 to exit): ");
int num = input.nextInt();
int count =0;

while(num!=0 ){
    if(count<=3){
        if (num % 2 == 1 ) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(num + " is half-prime ");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(num + " is not half-prime ");
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 100: (0 to exit): ");
    num = input.nextInt();
}
```

I think I've written the count part wrong ! Can someone help me !!

Comment: what is count . where is it coming from . why arent you clearing it at the end

Comment: You will need at least two loops, one loop for repeatedly asking the user for input, and for each such input, a second loop to count the number of divisors. I'd suggest making a reusable/testable method for the inner loop logic, e.g. `static int countDivisors(int number)`.

Comment: @Andreas thank you for your respond ! i will try doing that.

Comment: Note that the only numbers that are "half prime", are the squares of primes. How many squares of primes between 1 and 100?